# Redux-thunk - dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm having trouble with redux-thunk. It's saying dispatch is not a function inside my action creator, I tried consoling the returned arguments and there is none.

Here goes the code:

**Action**

```js
export function signUp(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(dispatch)
    if (data.email === 'email@server.com') {
      dispatch(signIn(data, () => {
        if (data.type === '2') {
          browserHistory.push('/settings/profile')
        } else {
          browserHistory.push('/')
        }
      }))
    } else {
      return {
        type: ActionTypes.USER_SIGN_UP__ERROR
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

**mapActionsToProps**

```js
const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => ({
  signUp (data) {
    console.log(dispatch)
    dispatch(userActions.signUp(data))
  }
})
```

By the way, you can see I consoled the dispatch function inside the mapActionsToProps, and it is returning as it was supposed to:

```js
  function (action) {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch is not a function, because it's not passed from action creator.

Besides, you should not dispatch any action inside your mapActionsToProps. You just need to bind them to be accessible by connected component.

**Your mapActionsToProps**

```
const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    asyncAction: bindActionCreators(asyncAction, dispatch),
  }
}

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(Component);
```

**Async action**

```
export const asyncAction = (email) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    const state = getState();

    dispatch(StartAsync());

    return fetch(`${apiUrl}/endpoint?email=${email}`, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((result) => dispatch(finishedAsync(result)),
              (error) => dispatch(failedAsync(error)))
        .catch(e => {
          console.log('error:', e);
        });
  };
};
```

Then, in your connected component, you can dispatch this action from props.

Comment: Actually, according in the redux source code it is commented that `This [bindActionCreators function] is just a convenience method, as you can call "store.dispatch(MyActionCreators.doSomething())" yourself just fine`.

Besides that I don't see any real difference on our code structure, do get other differences? Thanks

Comment: You're right. I'm just used to bindActionCreators. Have you tried returning your function from `mapActionsToProps` ?

Comment: `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
     signUp: (data) => {
       dispatch(userActions.signUp(data))
     }
   }
 }`

Comment: Yeah, I just used a different way of writting, but I actually wrote just that.